# Where did the term "Spot color" originate?

Tags: color, print-design, color-theory, spot-color

In commercial printing, "spot colors" refers to specialized ink mixes to create a predetermined color. Pantone, Toyo, and others are brands of inks which specialize in the sale of "spot color" inks.

I know this already.

I recently became curious as to *why* the inks are called **"spot"**.

So I started researching. I can find definition after definition after definition of *what* "spot color" means, how it's used on press, desktops, applications, etcetera. However, I can not seem to find *anything* which explains **why** the term "spot" was originally used.

**Does anyone know where the term "spot", as related to special inks, originated?**

My guessing would lead me to think that it was coined because *that* color was only meant for *that* "spot", thus *"that spot of color"* became *"spot color"*. But that seems too simple and doesn't really explain the correlation to specialized color mixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *wikipedia* article on [*spot color*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_color):

> In offset printing, a spot color is any color generated by an ink
>   (pure or mixed) that is printed using a single run. [CMYKOG...] The
>   two additional spot colors are added to compensate for the ineffective
>   reproduction of faint tints using CMYK colors only. However, offset
>   technicians around the world use the term spot color to mean any color
>   generated by a non-standard offset ink; such as metallic, fluorescent,
>   or custom hand-mixed inks.

---

**A "tint"**

Beyond contemporary dictionaries ([*Oxford*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spot), [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spot)), the *PrintWiki - The Free Encyclopedia of Print* provides interesting details on [spot color](http://printwiki.org/Spot_Color) (a *specific region of a printed sheet* - so a "spot" as you say - and the fact that there is no need for color separation i.e. by contrast to how [*process colors*](http://printwiki.org/Process_Color) are used, etc.) and furthermore states that it is sometimes called a [*tint*](http://printwiki.org/Tint):

> In printing, an alternate term for flat tint. See Flat Tint.
>
> The term tint is also occasionally used as an alternate term for spot
>   color. See Spot Color.
>
> In subtractive color theory, tint refers to a primary hue to which
>   some quantity of white pigment has been added.
>
> The term tint is also an alternate term for saturation, or how white
>   (or light) a particular hue is. See Saturation.
>
> In ink mixing, a colored printing ink to which a quantity of extender
>   or white pigment has been added in order to reduce the color strength
>   of the primary color.
>
> In halftone photography, tint refers to a halftone produced with a dot
>   percentage of less than 100%.

---

**Etymology** ([**Online Etymology Dictionary**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=spot))

> **spot (n.)**
>
> c.1200, "moral stain," probably from Old English splott "a spot, blot,
>   patch (of land)," and partly from or related to Middle Dutch spotte
>   "spot, speck." Other cognates are East Frisian spot "speck," North
>   Frisian spot "speck, piece of ground," Old Norse spotti "small piece,"
>   Norwegian spot "spot, small piece of land." It is likely that some of
>   these are borrowed from others, but the exact evolution now is
>   impossible to trace.
>
> Meaning "speck, stain" is from mid-14c. The sense of "particular
>   place, small extent of space" is from c.1300. Meaning "short interval
>   in a broadcast for an advertisement or announcement" is from 1923.
>   Proceeded by a number (as in five-spot) it originally was a term for
>   "prison sentence" of that many years (1901, American English slang).
>   To put (someone) on the spot "place in a difficult situation" is from
>   1928. Colloquial phrase to hit the spot "satisfy, be what is required" is from 1868. Spot check first attested 1933. Adverbial phrase spot on
>   "completely right" attested from 1920.
>
> **spot (v.)**
>
> mid-13c., "to mark or stain with spots;" late 14c. as "to stain,
>   sully, tarnish," from spot (n.). Meaning "to see and recognize," is
>   from 1718, originally colloquial and applied to a criminal or
>   suspected person; the general sense is from 1860. Related: Spotted;
>   spotting. Spotted dick "suet pudding with currants and raisins" is
>   attested from 1849.
>
> **hue (n.1)**
>
> "color," Old English hiw "color, form, appearance, beauty," earlier
>   heow, hiow, from Proto-Germanic *hiwam (cognates: Old Norse hy "bird's
>   down," Swedish hy "skin, complexion," Gothic hiwi "form, appearance"),
>   from PIE *kei-, a color adjective of broad application (cognates:
>   Sanskrit chawi "hide, skin, complexion, color, beauty, splendor,"
>   Lithuanian šyvas "white"). A common word in Old English, squeezed into
>   obscurity after c.1600 by color, but revived 1850s in chemistry and
>   chromatography.
>
> **tinct (n.)**
>
> "color, tint," c.1600, from Latin tinctus "a dyeing," from tingere "to
>   dye" (see tincture).
>
> **tincture (n.)**
>
> c.1400, "a coloring, dye," from Latin tinctura "act of dyeing or
>   tingeing," from tinctus "dye," past participle of tingere "to tinge,
>   dye, soak in color," originally merely "to moisten, wet, soak," from
>   PIE root *teng- "to soak" (cognates: Old High German dunkon "to soak,"
>   Greek tengein "to moisten"). Meaning "solution of medicine in a
>   mixture of alcohol" is first recorded 1640s. The verb is recorded from
>   1610s. Related: Tinctured.

So the noun can mean amongst other things something close to "compliant" or "be right". The verb can mean something close to "fill" as well as "identify". Historically, *hue* comes before *color* and *tint* involves some type of process.

---

**U.S. Very late 19th ([*The Century Dictionary*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_Dictionary), 1890s)**

This source details many meanings of *spot*, but it contains no reference whatsoever to spot color. Yet the *supplement* contains [*spotter*](http://triggs.djvu.org/century-dictionary.com/djvu2jpgframes.php?volno=12&page=504&query=spotter) used differently than in the main [work](http://triggs.djvu.org/century-dictionary.com/djvu2jpgframes.php?volno=07&page=543&query=spotter)(one who spots, a detective):

> [...]4. One who tints photographs.

So could there be some relationship to a specialized field of that era i.e. [tinting of photographs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinted_photograph), where *[a] single overall colour underlies the image and is most apparent in the highlights and mid-tones*? See also [*hand coloring*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand-colouring). In *Dictionary.com* there is also a photography-related meaning, but in a different light, as in *spotting*(retouching): *to remove spots from (a negative or print) by covering with opaque color*. So a *spotter* colorizes whereas *spotting* involves small patches on specific spots for retouching.

---

**Quick comparison: *French***

The French version of the article on spot color is called "[Ton direct](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ton_direct)":

> Le ton direct en imprimerie est le fait d'imprimer une **teinte
>   directement** sans passer par l'utilisation du spectre CMJN.

That word is *tint*, from the same *latin* origin. The English language is trying to express something like "to print a tint directly". The context is *hue* had been replaced with *color* historically. So is it a "spot on/for the spot/on the spot/hitting the spot" color in reference to that too i.e. of a specific tint/for a specific print job/directly/complying with expectations? It certainly seems to be about "peculiar parameters" for an ink tailored to a job so as to enable a simpler print process.

---

**Observations**

This exploration supports no conclusion. Observations could be that it seems a lot about colors for specific "spots" like you said. At the same time, the word *spot* has a rich texture. Photographic techniques are central to modern 20th century printing and the study of color from the middle of the 19th was key in specializing/rediscovering words related to color and developing processes. At that time, a *spotter* used to be someone who tinted photographs - in some cases by hand. The idea of spot color may also be independently linked to an exact *tint* and that is somewhat related to a "direct" process which contrasts with printing using transparent inks i.e. by layer.

Hopefully this can assist someone with expertise in connecting the [spots](http://printwiki.org/Spot)!

Comment: @Scott You're welcome! Words always have some interesting stories to tell; and discovering that _Century_ dictionary was quite satisfying in that respect... Color is fascinating.

Answer (score 1):

Because this type of color printing (low cost, letterpress, almost always black plus one or maybe two other inks) was really only capable of printing spots of color -- distinct regions. The term Spot color contrasts with reproduction of continuous tone images (photographs) or multicolor images (like comics) the require CMYK (process or 4-color) printing.